# Launch storyboard - how to change the image?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Our app is released, but we are working on a new version, and in this version we are using a launch storyboard instead of images in the asset catalog.

In our testing with this app in development, it seems like it creates the launch image on the device, and if we change the image, those devices we used before will continue to use the old image and not change.  If we get another device, it will use whatever version of the image we have at the time.

Is this behavior others are seeing?  Can we change this image in the future during upgrade of the app?  Is this issue that we are doing development builds and not going through the store?

Comment: try to manually remove previous installation from the device

Comment: We've been deleting the app from the device, cleaning the build folder, even turning off the device, and we keep seeing that first image.

Comment: Cached data stored in the "DerivedData" folder, try to clean it

Comment: We did delete the DerivedData folder for the project.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue for last 10 days :(